# Unpack JSON and expand using current data in other fields in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Suggest I have data of the format in one field of (some nested) JSON:

```
Name       Identifier                Data
Joe        54872                     [{"ref":{"type":4,"id":86669},"side":"Buy","ratio":1},{"ref":{"type":4,"id":80843},"side":"Sell","ratio":1}]
Jill       84756                     [{"ref":{"type":4,"id":75236},"side":"Buy","ratio":1},{"ref":{"type":4,"id":75565},"side":"Sell","ratio":1}]
```

Is there a simplistic way, rather than unpacking the json into it's own dataframe then concatenating it with the fixed data for each row of len(n) where n is the length of each json dataframe, to produce the following data?

```
Name      Identifier       ref_type      ref_id      side     ratio
Joe       54872            4             86669       buy      1
Joe       54872            4             80843       sell     1
Jill      84756            4             75236       buy      1
Jill      84756            4             75565       sell     1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `print (df['Data'].apply(type))` ?

Comment: 306    <type 'unicode'>
358    <type 'unicode'>
360    <type 'unicode'>
Name: Data, dtype: object

Comment: You input is json file? Is possible use my solution in answer?

Comment: Input is not JSON file - the input is a dataframe where one field contains JSON, as shown in the first table in the question.

Comment: I edit answer, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best is use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

df = json_normalize(data)
```

EDIT:

If not possible use:

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#convert strings to lists and dicts
df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#parse Data column
df1 = pd.concat([json_normalize(x) for x in df['Data'].values.tolist()], keys= df.index)
#append to original
df1 = df.drop('Data', 1).join(df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   Name  Identifier  ratio  ref.id  ref.type  side
0   Joe       54872      1   86669         4   Buy
1   Joe       54872      1   80843         4  Sell
2  Jill       84756      1   75236         4   Buy
3  Jill       84756      1   75565         4  Sell
```