# Python API JSON Output Flatten - List within Response

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm trying to completely flatten my json response from an API into a pandas dataframe and have no idea how to flatten out a list of objects within the response - This relates to the "Lines" column located in the documentation [here](https://developer.myob.com/api/myob-business-api/v2/generalledger/journaltransaction/) and below.

```
"Lines" : [
{
"Account" : {
"UID" : "17960eb4-3e14-4805-aae2-5b2387da1153",
"Name" : "Trade Debtors",
"DisplayID" : "1-1310",
"URI" : "{cf_uri}/GeneralLedger/Account/17960eb4-3e14-4805-aae2-5b2387da1153"
},
"Amount" : 100,
"IsCredit" : false,
"Job" : null,
"LineDescription" : ""
"ReconciledDate" : null,
"UnitCount": null
},
{
"Account" : {
"UID" : "f7d18c92-ada8-428e-b02a-9223022f84b2",
"Name" : "Late Fees Collected",
"DisplayID" : "4-3000",
"URI" : "{cf_uri}/GeneralLedger/Account/f7d18c92-ada8-428e-b02a-9223022f84b2"
},
"Amount" : 90.91,
"IsCredit" : true,
"Job" : null,
"LineDescription" : "Line 1 testing",
"UnitCount": null
},
{
"Account" : {
"UID" : "5427d47c-499a-4386-ad67-72de39520a00",
"Name" : "GST Collected",
"DisplayID" : "2-1210",
"URI" : "{cf_uri}/GeneralLedger/Account/5427d47c-499a-4386-ad67-72de39520a00"
},
"Amount" : 9.09,
"IsCredit" : true,
"Job" : null,
"LineDescription" : "",
"ReconciledDate" : null,
"UnitCount": null
}
],
```

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

payload={}
headers = {
  'x-myobapi-key': client_id,
  'x-myobapi-version': 'v2',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

result = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(result, 'Items')


while result['NextPageLink'] is not None:
  response = requests.request("GET", result['NextPageLink'], headers=headers, data=payload)
  result = response.json()

  df1 = pd.json_normalize(result, 'Items')
  df = df.append(df1)
```

This code above appends each page of results until there isn't a link, as you can see the following output was able to expand the `SourceTransactions` columns but not the `Lines` columns as it appears to be in list format?
In order for me to access lines I need to use the following `result["Items"][0]["Lines"]` except that's only for the first element

```
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| UID  | DisplayID | JournalType | DateOccurred | DatePosted | Description |             Lines              |          URI           | RowVersion | SourceTransaction.UID | SourceTransaction.TransactionType | SourceTransaction.URI |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| a100 | PJ001     | Purchase    | 2022-01-01   | 2022-01-01 | Transaction | [{'Account': {'UID': '73971... | https://arl1.api.my... |       -139 | e06f592c-23b          | Bill                              | https://arl1.api...   |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example of an element of `Lines`?

Comment: Is there an association between adjacent elements on the list? And if so, what is it?

Comment: Each row represents a transaction, I downloaded a .json file of the output in Postman and opened it in Power Query. The option for expanding the Lines column asks to "Expanded to New Rows". So within each "Lines" element there are 2-4 rows, which would line up with the one unnested row. Basically identical to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765421/unpack-json-and-expand-using-current-data-in-other-fields-in-pandas)

Comment: The reason I asked is that the dictionaries in the list have different keys. So you would end up with a lot of null values if you expanded it that way, and I'm nbot sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Zorgoth I ended up working it out using 1 line of code. However, this didn't unpack the 'SourceTransactions' nested array.
`df5 = pd.json_normalize(data=result["Items"], record_path='Lines', meta=['UID', 'DisplayID','JournalType','DateOccurred','DatePosted','Description','URI','RowVersion'])`

Comment: @zorgoth You were right, upon further inspection of the dataframe it created a lot of null values, even with what I attempted above.

Answer (score 0):

For others that stumble across the same problem, turns out reading the documentation helped me - Who knew?!

I just needed to make a few tweaks with the json_normalize function. Also the order you type the meta parameters in matters, so you'll need to ensure your order matches the API documentation.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=result["Items"], record_path='Lines', meta=['UID',
'DisplayID','JournalType', ['SourceTransaction', 'UID'], ['SourceTransaction', 'TransactionType'], ['SourceTransaction',
'URI'], 'DateOccurred','DatePosted','Description','URI','RowVersion'])
```